# Deliver more then one file from s3 with django

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Is it possible to generate a url that will deliever more then one image at a time?

I know you can do this:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_bucket')
s3_file_path = bucket.get_key('path/to/file')
url = s3_file_path.generate_url(expires_in=600) # expiry time is in seconds
```

but this will only do one file at a time, is there a way to make it do more then one?

edit for clarification: Ideally it would be delivered as a zip, but doing multiple files consecutively wouldn't be bad either

Comment: Ideally yes that would be preferred, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible since it is not supported by AWS. [GET Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) supports one object only. You may find other(third party like s3cmd) solutions that allow you to get multiple objects with single command but at the low level, it will loop through the object list and make multiple GET calls.